Physics site-wide metrics on things like question closure/deletion rates etc?
It seems it would be very useful to see a summary of metrics such as question closure rates, perhaps broken down by moderator and reason, so the community can get a sense of the current trends and perhaps identify improvement pathways.  As one frequently hears something along the lines of: in order to fix something, you need to measure it first.
Having these metrics publicly visible would be a great feature to the platform.  Perhaps these are already readily available in the "back-end," created by the data-scientists/analysts that work for Stack Exchange.
Thank you.

What kind of improvement?

Most questions are NOT closed by mods but by users with sufficient rep to have the vote-to-close privilege.

These metrics are all available on SE data explorer: https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/queries Contrary to a belief, you do NOT need reputation-gated tools to access that data.
However, you DO need to know computer code well enough to compose custom queries. Do not worry if you don't, as the specific queries might have already been composed by someone else, and might be accessible from the selection list.

... and, honestly, a well-phrased request (either as a question on this meta or on [chat]) can often bring forward folks who can code up the relevant SQL query.

Note that the Data Explorer does not contain closure reasons (and therefore community-specific reasons).

Statistics on question closure and reopen rates are already available with the moderator tools privilege, which requires 10000 reputation. They contain breakdowns by closure reason and community-specifc reasons, for up to the past 90 days.
Publicly available yearly stats can also be found here. It contains breakdowns by reason but not community-specific reasons.
The Stack Exchange Data Explorer can also be used to count the number of closures for any time span. For non-deleted posts, it contains the reason for closure. For deleted posts, it does not contain the reason for closure.
